# Retrieve a value from sqli_query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to retrieve the highest userID in my sql table. I am using sqli_query function in PHP. I know this function returns an object. How can I assign the returned userID to a variable?

```
    $query = "SELECT max(UserID) FROM userinfo";
    $highID = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    if (!$highID) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($highID, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

        echo "{$rows['UserID']}";
    }
```

this is the error I get

> Notice: Undefined index: UserID in C:\Apache24\htdocs\dbpractice\info.php on line 165

Comment: `$query = "SELECT max(UserID) as maxId FROM userinfo";` then no need to loop just fetch with `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($highID, MYSQL_ASSOC)` and get by `$rows['maxId']`

Comment: you are fetching `max(UserID)` in the query. So `UserID` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT max(UserID) as maxUserID FROM userinfo";
```

Now you can use

```
$rows["maxUserID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo ORDER BY UserID DESC LIMIT 1
```

That's the query i do without any problem. Hope it works for you.